# Check box not responding to click in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, checkbox, onchange

I have a simple react component that has a check box i want to toggle the value for on a click, it seems like it completely ignores my click I cant even get a console log. No idea why this doesnt work

```
export const InputCheckbox: InputCheckboxComponent = ({ id, checked = false, disabled, onChange }) => {
  const { current: inputId } = useRef(`RampInputCheckbox-${id}`)
  

  const handleClick = () => console.log('click');
  return (
    <div className="RampInputCheckbox--container" data-testid={inputId}>
      <label
        className={classNames("RampInputCheckbox--label", {
          "RampInputCheckbox--label-checked": checked,
          "RampInputCheckbox--label-disabled": disabled,
        })}
      />
      <input
        id={inputId}
        type="checkbox"
        className="RampInputCheckbox--input"
        onChange={handleClick}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I've tried changing to onClick and I noticed the component isn't re-rendering on the click

Comment: Add `const [ checked, setChecked ] = useState(false)` and then use it for the input prop `value={checked}`. In `handleClick`, add `setChecked(!checked)`

Comment: I've copied your `input` and the handler into a sandbox react page and it works fine and calls `console.log`. There is something else on your page or code that prevents the handler to work properly in your setup.

Comment: There is a parent component that might be doing it?
```  return (
      <InputCheckbox
        id={transaction.id}
        checked={approved}
        disabled={loading}
        onChange={async (newValue) => {
          await consumerSetTransactionApproval({
            transactionId: transaction.id,
            newValue,
          })
          setApproved(newValue)
        }}
      />
  ) ```
}